# CentOS: a network interface with multiple IRQ numbers?

Tags: linux, centos, network-interface

I have a network interface named `em1` in my server.

I use the command `cat /proc/interrupts` and I get :

```
       CPU0       CPU1    
105： 257193915   0     IR-PCI-MSI-edge em1-0
106:  116002780   0     IR-PCI-MSI-edge em1-1
```

My question is why my NIC has more than one IRQ number?

Comment: What is the model of the NIC?

Answer (score 2):

NIC drivers create an interrupt receive queue per CPU (Receive side scaling) and hence you see 2 irq's. Some drivers allow this to be configured. Read this for more info https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/networking/scaling.txt

Comment: so you're saying there are two IRQs because there are two CPUs?

Comment: Yes, see more from updated link in my answer